# ctrl + // to toggle "comment"

Tags: visual-studio

Is it possible to replace <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> to just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>?
I want to replace 2 hotkeys with 1 hotkey that "toggle" either text is commented or uncomented.

I.e. similar to Eclipse

Comment: What does "toggle comment" do to a line that begins with `////`?

Comment: no, to uncomment line. this is how it works in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe its possible to replace two hotkeys with 1 hotkey in visual studio. However you can create two hotkeys that are very similar in order to more easily toggle a comment.

An example would be:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + 
<kbd>/</kbd> = Comment

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + 
<kbd>/</kbd> = Uncomment

You can do this by going into the Tools -> Options menu.
Selecting "Keyboard" in the list box to the left.

Then type "comment" in the [Show commands containing:] textbox.

Assign your desired hot keys to:
Edit.CommentSelection 
Edit.UncommentSelection

Hope that helps.